# 301 redirect works in Firefox but not Safari or Chrome?

Tags: http-status-code-301

I have this simple redirect at the top of my htaccess to redirect a Wordpress category archive to a new page. It works on firefox but not other browsers. If I eliminate the category I get a 404 error.

```
Redirect 301 /category/forums-and-events/  /forums-and-events/
```

I've emptied the browsers' cache. What can I do to get it to work?

Comment: I tried absolute urls and had no luck with that either. Is there something wrong with the format of the 301?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress this works for redirecting to an absolute url and avoids htaccess:

```
<?php
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
?>
```

$location is the url to direct to, $status is either 301 (permanent redirect) or 302 (temporary)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect